# django - клик на категорию, чтобы вывести все услуги данной категории

Tags: django

всем привет! при клике на категорию, я вывожу субкатегории, которые принадлежат конкретной категории.
но не понимаю, как мне дальше при клике на субкатегорию выводить все услуги, которые принадлежат данной субкатегории. думал, что это решается условием , типа {% if category == ... %}... как уже только не пробовал. но ничего не работает. после того, как смогу сделать проверку и выводить все услуги субкатегории, буду прикручить htmx, чтобы выводить услуги без перезагрузки страницы.

```
<!-- Этот блок для вывода категорий и их субкатегорий -->
<div class="services__categories-list">
  <p>Выберите интересующий вас пункт. Не знаете с чего начать? Кликните на пункт Консультирование и запишитесь на прием к нужному врачу.</p>
  <ul> {% for category in categories %} <li class="services__categories-item">
      <h3 class="services__categories-list__item">&#10059; {{ category.name }}</h3>
      <div class="submenu">
        <ul> {% for cat in category.get_children %} <li>
            <h4>
              <a href="">{{ cat.name }}</a>
            </h4>
          </li> {% endfor %} </ul>
      </div>
    </li> {% endfor %} </ul>
</div>
 
 
<!-- Тут должны выводиться услуги конкретной подкатегории при клике на {{ cat.name }} из предыдущего блока -->
<div class="services__items"> {% for service in services %} <div id="services__inner" class="services__inner">
    <div class="services__items__item">
      <div class="services__items__item__name">
        <h5>{{ service.name }}</h5>
        <div class="services__items__item__name__categories">
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__icon">
            <img src="{% static 'img/line.svg' %}" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__category">
            <p>{{ service.category }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__description container-md">
        <a>описание <span class="decoration-text-md">и</span> подготовка </a>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__price container-sm">
        <div class="services__items__item__price__digits">
          <p>{{ service.price }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services__items__item__price__icon">
          <img src="{% static 'img/rub.svg' %}" alt="" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service__items__item__specification">
      <div class="service__items__item__specification__inner">
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__inner__definition">
          <h6>описание</h6>
          <p>{{ service.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__inner__preparation">
          <h6>подготовка</h6>
          <p>{{ service.preparation }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> {% endfor %} </div>
 
<!-- views.py -->
 
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Service, Doctor, Document, Category
 
def main(request):
    """Вывод главной страницы"""
    services = Service.objects.all()
    doctors = Doctor.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.filter(parent=None)
    return render(request, "main/main.html", 
        {"services": services, "doctors": doctors, "categories": categories, "branch_categories": branch_categories})
 
def docs(request):
    """Вывод страницы с документами"""
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    return render(request, "main/docs.html", {"documents": documents})
 
<!-- models.py -->
 
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
 
class Category(MPTTModel):
    """Описание категории услуг"""
    name = models.CharField("Категория", max_length=255)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        'self', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True, 
        blank=True,
        db_index=True,
        related_name="children",
        verbose_name="Главная категория"
    )
 
    class MPTTMeta:
        """Сортировка по вложенности"""
        order_insertion_by = ("name",)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Категория"
        verbose_name_plural = "Категории"
        db_table = "app_categories"
 
 
class Service(models.Model):
    """Описание услуги"""
    name = models.CharField("Услуга", max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    preparation = models.TextField("Подготовка")
    price = models.CharField("Цена", max_length=8)
    category = TreeForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="категория", related_name="categories")
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Услуга"
        verbose_name_plural = "Услуги"
 
 
class Doctor(models.Model):
    """Описание специалиста"""
    name = models.CharField("Имя специалиста", max_length=255)
    bio = models.TextField("Описание", null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to="doctors/")
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Специалист"
        verbose_name_plural = "Специалисты"
 
 
class Document(models.Model):
    """Описание документа"""
    name = models.CharField("Название документа", max_length=255)
    doc = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/")
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Документ"
        verbose_name_plural = "Документы"
```